# Change image on tkinter without button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Can anyone explain me how to use correctly the mainloop?
I am trying to update an image depending on a condition,the problem is that all seems to work but the image on the canvas is not changing.

```
from tkinter import *

class Panel():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.frame1= Frame(master, width=500, height=500)
        self.frame1.pack()

        self.canvas1 = Canvas(self.frame1, width=1000, height=1000)
        self.canvas1.grid(row=0 , column=0)
        self.canvas1.pack()
        self.images=[]
        self.images.append(PhotoImage(file="download-icones-png-1.png"))
        self.images.append(PhotoImage(file="Download-Icon.png"))
        self.number = 0
        self.image_on_canvas = self.canvas1.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = self.images[self.number])
        #self.update_image()

    def update_image(self):
        if(self.number == 1):
            print("Current number is:",self.number)
            self.canvas1.itemconfig(self.image_on_canvas, image=self.images[self.number])
            self.number = 0
            print("The number change to:", self.number)
            self.canvas1.after(2000, self.update_image)
        elif(self.number==0):
            print("Current number is:",self.number)
            self.number = 1
            self.canvas1.itemconfig(self.image_on_canvas, image=self.images[self.number])
            print("The number change to:", self.number)
            self.canvas1.after(2000, self.update_image)


def Main():
     root = Tk()
     cp=Panel(root)
     cp.update_image()
     root.mainloop()

Main()
```

Thanks

Solution:

```
self.canvas1.after(2000, self.update_image)
```

Must be outside the if statement

Comment: Try uncommenting the `self.update_image()` then instead of having the `self.canvas1.after(2000, self.update_image)` inside the if statements put it at the start/end of the function.

Comment: I put the  self.canvas1.after(2000, self.update_image) outside the function and is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to update an image depending on a condition, the problem
> is that all seems to work but the image on the canvas is not changing.

Don't use append for images.

- In line 13, change `self.images.append(PhotoImage..` to
  `self.images=PhotoImage((file="p1.png")`
- In line 14, change `self.images.append(PhotoImage..` to
  `self.images1=PhotoImage((file="p2.png")`
- In line 16, change `image = self.images[self.number]` to `image = self.images`
- In `update_image` function line 22,  change
  `image=self.images[self.number]` to `image=self.images`
- In `update_image` function line 25, comment out
  `#self.canvas1.after(5000, self.update_image)`
- In `update_image` function line 29,  change
  `image=self.images[self.number]` to `image=self.images1`
- In `update_image` function line 31, put this outside of
  `update_image` function.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

class Panel():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.frame1= Frame(master, width=500, height=500)
        self.frame1.pack()

        self.canvas1 = Canvas(self.frame1, width=1000, height=1000)
        self.canvas1.grid(row=0 , column=0)
        #self.canvas1.pack()
        self.images=[]
        self.images=PhotoImage(file="p1.png") 
        self.images1=PhotoImage(file="p2.png") 
        self.number = 0
        self.image_on_canvas = self.canvas1.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image=self.images)
         

    def update_image(self):
        if(self.number == 1):
            print("Current number is:",self.number)
            self.canvas1.itemconfig(self.image_on_canvas, image=self.images)
            self.number = 0
            print("The number change to:", self.number)
            #self.canvas1.after(5000, self.update_image)
        elif(self.number==0):
            print("Current number is:",self.number)
            self.number = 1
            self.canvas1.itemconfig(self.image_on_canvas, image=self.images1)
            print("The number change to:", self.number)
        self.canvas1.after(5000, self.update_image)


def Main():
     root = Tk()
     cp=Panel(root)
     cp.update_image()
     root.mainloop()

Main()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey This problem occurs because after setting a image to the label it collects a garbage value that's why we are unable to change it  but you can get your work done by doing this :

```
#First in your command line type this -- pip install pillow
from PIL import Image, ImageTK
image= Image.open(image_path)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
""" 
Here instead of PhotoImage(file=PATH) use the above and 
then as you have done in your code just append it in the 
list . -- enjoy 
"""
```

Comment: this is probably not the issue as nothing actually really gets collected in the method since it uses instance attributes so this solves about nothing?

Comment: According to me when  I was working on my project . This problem also happened with me and the above code solved the problem and after a bit of search I found that label stores a garbage value like cookies in websites

Comment: @Mr.Expert First of all, there is no point to using `PILImageTk.PhotoImage. It looks like `tkinter.PhotoImage` is enough. Second of all, the images are stored inside `self.images` and that variable doesn't get garbage collected until the `Main` function is done. That happens after all of the `tkinter` windows are closed. At that point you should want the images to be garbage collected.